# Suggestions for all routes passing by 2 points

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, breadth-first-search, bellman-ford

I am dealing with a math question, which is a road goes through 2 points randomly. And that road must be the shortest.

[image]

For example:

i want to go from A to D, it will suggest AD, AE(ADE), AC(ADEC), AF(ADF)

From D to E  it will suggest DE, DC(DEC), AE(ADE), AC(ADEC), BE(BDE), BC(BDEC), FE(FDE)

From B to E  it will suggest BE, AE(ABE), AC(ABEC), BC(BEC)

From B to D  it will suggest BD, BF(BDF), BC(BDFC), BE(BDE), BC(BDEC)

Ps/
I using the dijkstra algorithm, it only finds routes starting at the origin point.
Example: From D to E, it only suggests DE and (DC)DEC
Now I want to suggest more AE(ADE), AC(ADEC), BE(BDE), BC(BDEC), FE(FDE) (routes before starting point).

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!!!

Comment: To clarify, are you asking for an algorithm that generates all node pairs (x,y) such that the shortest path p(x,y) passes through a given pair of points (p,q)?

Comment: @Keith  that's right. Ex: 

From D to E it will suggest DE, DC, AE, AC,BE, BC, FE

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is called [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and based on the graphs and points it lets you to find the shortest path. I've made it on my site it's in polish but you can see the code and usage there http://blog.rpodwika.pl/algorytm-dijkstry-php/

Comment: Thanks Robert,
 find the shortest path is ok.
But I want suggestions for routes passing 2 points
Can you help me!!!!

Comment: you can use the class from my blog and see $path in process method it contains the shortest route.

Comment: I'm the owner of the site :) I won't change the link however you're right :) I just didn't want to paste whole class here.

Comment: Hi Robert, can you help me this code, I will pay for your help!

Comment: Hi Robert, I using the dijkstra algorithm, it only finds routes starting at the origin point.
Example: From D to E, it only suggests DE and DEC
Now I want to suggest more ADE, ADEC, BDE, BDEC, FDE (routes before starting point).

Comment: I think this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901833/how-to-reconstruct-paths-from-a-multi-path-dijkstra

Comment: I'm so awkward, Can you give me the complete code to run the above diagram ?! Thank @Robert so much!

Comment: @Robert, In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901833/how-to-reconstruct-paths-from-a-multi-path-dijkstra

The code in link you send for me, how to use?
Written in class Dijkstra or outside class?